# Java code to generate random string based on regex

Tags: java

Java code to generate random string based on regex. I tried generex library , but it's not giving exact output. For example:

```
       Generex generex = new Generex("^[6-9]\\d{9}$");
       System.out.println(generex.random());
```

Output is : ^8677547981$ 
while i was expecting output to be 8677547981.It seems generex is not able to handle special characters like "^" , "$" etc.

Can someone pls help?

Comment: Try escaping the dollar sign: `\\$`

Answer (score 5):

Generex doesn't need `^` and `$`. The content created by it matches the regex fully, instead of a partial match.

```
Generex generex = new Generex("[6-9]\\d{9}");
System.out.println(generex.random());
```

Comment: The point is not that it generates the full string, but that ^ and $ are valid regex characters but it is treating them like literals.  It should handle a valid regex without modification without introducing extraneous characters that would cause subsequent regex validation to fail.

Comment: @JeffVincent You should register that bug at the Generex project, if there isn't a duplicate already, I'm not affiliated with the project

Answer (score 2):

Generex uses `dk.brics.automaton.RegExp` class. It supports another set of regular expression operations as `java.util.regex.Pattern`. See [RegExp API](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/index.html?dk/brics/automaton/RegExp.html)